# (anonymous): Line 1:20 Unexpected token : while adding node to private ethereum network

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I'm trying to setup 2 node ethereum network in my local desktop one on port 30305 and another on 30305.

set up Node 1 -

```
$ ./build/bin/geth --datadir data/node1  --port 30304  --networkid 1234 init genesis/genesis.json
WARN [11-05|01:07:35] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default 
INFO [11-05|01:07:35] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/rajkumar/Coding/ethereum/go-ethereum/data/node1/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [11-05|01:07:35] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                                                            hash=a3c5c1…d6926b
INFO [11-05|01:07:35] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/rajkumar/Coding/ethereum/go-ethereum/data/node1/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [11-05|01:07:35] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                                                            hash=a3c5c1…d6926b
[rajkumar@localhost go-ethereum]$ ./build/bin/geth --datadir data/node1  --port 30304  --networkid 1234 console 2>console-node1.log
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.7.1-unstable-0956967e/linux-amd64/go1.9
modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> admin.peers
```

Set up Node 2 -

```
 $ ./build/bin/geth --datadir data/node2  --port 30305  --networkid 1234 init genesis/genesis.json 
 WARN [11-05|01:08:12] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default 
 INFO [11-05|01:08:12] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/rajkumar/Coding/ethereum/go-ethereum/data/node2/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
 INFO [11-05|01:08:12] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                                                            hash=a3c5c1…d6926b
 INFO [11-05|01:08:12] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/rajkumar/Coding/ethereum/go-ethereum/data/node2/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
 INFO [11-05|01:08:12] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                                                            hash=a3c5c1…d6926b
 [rajkumar@localhost go-ethereum]$ ./build/bin/geth --datadir data/node2  --port 30305  --networkid 1234 console 2>console-node2.log
 Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

 instance: Geth/v1.7.1-unstable-0956967e/linux-amd64/go1.9
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

 > admin.nodeInfo
 { enode:"enode://c9b201a3a5e478f059c909b3db1d595e8aa9b3a8ba254eb8830441934ca58f079db8b0bf247d06249a50eafb3372d8d8d5b4df0bf3171530832959279928a329@[::]:30305",


  id: "c9b201a3a5e478f059c909b3db1d595e8aa9b3a8ba254eb8830441934ca58f079db8b0bf247d06249a50eafb3372d8d8d5b4df0bf3171530832959279928a329",
  ip: "::",
  listenAddr: "[::]:30305",
  name: "Geth/v1.7.1-unstable-0956967e/linux-amd64/go1.9",
  ports: {
    discovery: 30305,
    listener: 30305
  },
  protocols: {
    eth: {
      difficulty: 131072,
      genesis: "0xa3c5c170988f516e00ea3078b2461a149bcd4d0422c8c894923c6cfa22d6926b",
      head: "0xa3c5c170988f516e00ea3078b2461a149bcd4d0422c8c894923c6cfa22d6926b",
      network: 1234
    }
  }
}
>
```

ip configuration of my laptop is -

```
$ ifconfig|grep netmask|awk '{print $2}'
10.0.2.15
127.0.0.1
```

Adding node2 to ethereum network -

```
  >admin.addpeer(enode://c9b201a3a5e478f059c909b3db1d595e8aa9b3a8ba254eb8830441934ca58f079db8b0bf247d06249a50eafb3372d8d8d5b4df0bf3171530832959279928a329@[::]:30305)
 (anonymous): Line 1:20 Unexpected token :

 >admin.addpeer(enode://c9b201a3a5e478f059c909b3db1d595e8aa9b3a8ba254eb8830441934ca58f079db8b0bf247d06249a50eafb3372d8d8d5b4df0bf3171530832959279928a329@localhost:30305)
 (anonymous): Line 1:20 Unexpected token :

 >admin.addpeer(enode://c9b201a3a5e478f059c909b3db1d595e8aa9b3a8ba254eb8830441934ca58f079db8b0bf247d06249a50eafb3372d8d8d5b4df0bf3171530832959279928a329@127.0.0.1:30305)
 (anonymous): Line 1:20 Unexpected token :

 >admin.addpeer(enode://c9b201a3a5e478f059c909b3db1d595e8aa9b3a8ba254eb8830441934ca58f079db8b0bf247d06249a50eafb3372d8d8d5b4df0bf3171530832959279928a329@10.0.2.15:30305)
 (anonymous): Line 1:20 Unexpected token :
```

As mentioned above, I have tried all combinations of [::], localhost, 127.0.0.1 and 10.0.2.15 which is actual ip config of my laptop but still I'm getting same error in the addpeer command.

Also, I haven't provided `--nodiscover` option  while creating any of the nodes.

Anyone knows the reason for this error?

Comment: just to be sure, you execute `admin.addpeer()` in node1's terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

geth console it's plain javascript console. It's support javascript syntax, you're missing the quotes `" "`:

```
admin.addpeer("enode://c32........9@[::]:30305") 
              ^_______________________________^
```

Comment: your suggestion worked!!! I've accepted your answer!!!